# Why ObjectAnimator.cancel() doesn't always work?

Tags: android, animation

So there are a few questions about animations not ending when using `cancel()` on them. You also need to call `clearAnimation` on the view. Can someone explain why is that? It's also very strange to me, that the `View` needs to know about what animates it.

Comment: What OS are you using?  I've never experienced this.  `clearnAnimation` on Views don't use the `Animator` framework.  They use the old `Animation` framework so neither should affect the other.

Comment: Android 4.0+. Maybe it's worth noting I cancel animation on keypress.

Comment: So when you call cancel without clearAnimation, the animation continues to completion?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call clear animation to reset the transformation matrix that the view is using to transform its canvas during the animation. The main problem is that old Android animation system is a crap since it relied on animating a "snapshot" of the actual view.
As for the cancel, when you invoke cancel what happens is that you stop the runnable that is applying the steps of your Animation. Of course you cannot be sure in which state your animation is getting stopped

Comment: That's different for ObjectAnimators though.  They change the physical properties of the View

Comment: It depends on the os version you are running on. NineOldAndroids re-implements object animators on old android versions using the old animation system

Comment: Ok.  He didn't say he was using NineOldAndroids.  Although, would it still have the same problem on 3.0+?  I would think NineOldAndroids would default to supported Animator framework in that case.

Comment: Yes on newer devices it will use the new animation system

Comment: Right.  He's on 4.0+ so this shouldn't have been an issue then.  That's all I'm saying.  I've never had a problem like this with Animators so just trying to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear:

- The View Animation Framework , a.k.a "old animation framework", only animates the translations of the view, and not the actual properties. So lets say you animate the view's location on the X dimention: the value of the view's X property remains the same.

  In relevance to your question, this means that canceling the animation draws the view      back in its original position. So it doesnt matter when did the animation was canceled.
- Object animation, introduced in Android 3.0, animates the actual properties. This means that when you cancel the animation, the view remains in its relevant position. So you might not know exactly WHEN was the animation canceled, but you can clearly find out WHERE is it drawn right now.
- If you need object animation for older versions of Android, and frankly why go any other way, you can use the [9OldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library.

Mor on the difference between the animation frameworks [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).